# Drop down List Not working in Open Office

Tags: openoffice-calc

i have created a file using MS Excel and saved the file as ODS but it will open on read only mode works perfectly but once i saved the file drop down list not working

Comment: The only way you'll attract more attention to your question is if you improve it. Add more details, tell us what you tried and also give your question a title that makes it instantly clear what exactly your issue is. This makes it a lot easier for users to spot your question if they know the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the spreadsheet in read only mode. copy all the data into new spreadsheet and save it. And apply filter using ALT+D+F+F. it will surely help you Out